# Getting distinct total results from RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I have an index :

```
from rest in docs 
from prom in rest.RestPromotions
```

When querying with LuceneQuery the TotalResults is more than expected because of the duplicate documents created by the index.
The skipped field has only the skipped results from the current page.

Is there a way to get the distinct total results?

The document type is like this:

```
{
  "RestName": "Belini",
  "RestID": 1275,
  "SearchNotVisible": [
    "Beliny",
    "bellini"
  ],
  "RegionID": 4,
  "SubRegionID": 0,
  "CityID": 172,
  "AreaID": 5,
  "AvgPriceID": 3,
  "RestTypes": [
    58
  ],
  "FoodTypes": [
    1,
    16
  ],
  "RestSpecials": [],
  "RestProperties": [
    4
  ],
  "RestPromotions": [
    {
      "regionID": 4,
      "cityID": 172,
      "areaID": 0,
      "KosherID": 0,
      "foodTypeID": 16,
      "restTypeID": 0,
      "promotionNumber": 1,
      "isFalsePromo": false
    },
    {
      "regionID": 4,
      "cityID": 172,
      "areaID": 0,
      "KosherID": 0,
      "foodTypeID": 0,
      "restTypeID": 0,
      "promotionNumber": 1,
      "isFalsePromo": false
    },
    {
      "regionID": 4,
      "cityID": 172,
      "areaID": 0,
      "KosherID": 0,
      "foodTypeID": 1,
      "restTypeID": 0,
      "promotionNumber": 1,
      "isFalsePromo": false
    },
  "isKosher": false,
  "ReviewsScore": 3.709,
  "ReviewsAmount": 408,
  "Latitude": 32.060707,
  "Longitude": 34.765018
}
```

and when doing a LuceneQuery on the index :

```
from rest in docs 
from prom in rest.RestPromotions
select new {RestID=rest.RestID,RestName=rest.RestName,PromoCityID=prom.cityID}
```

the TotalResult is greater than the real amount of documents returned by the query.
I know this is because of duplicated documents that are made by the index.

What I want to know is if there is an option to get the real amount of distinct documents that a specific LuceneQuery has generated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your index map to:

```
from rest in docs 
select new
{
    rest.RestName,
    PromoCityID = rest.RestPromotions.Select(x=> x.cityID)
}
```

That will index multiple terms in one index entry, rather than having multiple index entries. You can still query it for a single term, just as before.  But now when you look at the statistics, the `TotalResults` will represent the total number of restaurants that matched.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but what i need is to be able to ask is if PromoCityID == X And foodTypeID == Y AND restTypeID == Z .... and all of them in the same RestPromotions item . in the way you posted i can only ask if one of the promotions has a specific cityid and one of the promotions has a specific foodtype and so on where actually i need the same promotion to have both of them and also my ordering is based on promotionNumber inside the RestPromotions that was found from this index .

Comment: Ok, understood.  Going with your original index, is subtracting the SkippedResults from the TotalResults good enough for you?  The only time this won't be accurate is if you are getting more than one page of results back, because SkippedResults only reflects results skipped up to the page you are reading.

Comment: I am getting pages so subtracting the skipped results is not good for me.

Comment: Doesn't appear that there is a good solution.  Sorry.  https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ravendb/MRrvUvas6_A

Comment: Thanks Matt . I solved it in a way that just counts a specific facet i have . and it works for now .