# RavenDB statistics.TotalResults returning incorrect value

Tags: ravendb

I have a problem that when using the following index. The problem is that when I am using `statistics.TotalResults` I am returning the count of all documents returned both for docs and `docRateCardInformationsItems`. Is there any way to exclude `docRateCardInformationsItems` from the totalResults, since I only need the amount of documents in docs?

```
 Map = docs => from doc in docs                          
 from docRateCardInformationsItem in doc.RateCardInformations.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {RateCardInformations_From = docRateCardInformationsItem.From,
     RateCardInformations_To = docRateCardInformationsItem.To,
     RateCardInformations_RateDaily = docRateCardInformationsItem.RateDaily,
     RateCardInformations_RateWeekly = docRateCardInformationsItem.RateWeekly, doc.Id, doc.Name}
```

Comment: I found a similar post but the problem is still not solved and there is no description of the workaround for this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490557/getting-distinct-total-results-from-ravendb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Raven 2.5 there are no simple solutions for this problem and the only way to solve this is by creating a separate query that returns all distinct id's within that query and then counting the results. This issue is solved in raven 3.0 since there is a replacement on for fan-out indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The `TotalResults` is the number of index entries in the index.
This type of index is called a fanout index, and it isn't really recommended.

```
Map = docs =>
    from doc in docs                          
    select new
    {
        RateCardInformations_From = doc.RateCardInformations.Select(x=>x.From),
        RateCardInformations_To =  doc.RateCardInformations.Select(x=>x.To),
        RateCardInformations_RateDaily =  doc.RateCardInformations.Select(x=>x.RateDaily),
        RateCardInformations_RateWeekly =  doc.RateCardInformations.Select(x=>x.RateWeekly),
        doc.Id,
        doc.Name
    }
```

Comment: I tried to do it this way but then the query does not work correctly, since i need to query a combination of ranges together. `q = q.Where(x => x.Informations.Any(x => (startDate >= x.From && startDate <= x.To) || (endDate >= x.From && endDate <= x.To)));`